# Proof of $C\left(n, k\right) = \frac{C\left(n, k-1\right) \cdot C(n - (k - 1), 1)}k$

Tags: combinatorics

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me why this holds true?

$$C\left(n, k\right) = \frac{C\left(n, k-1\right) \cdot C(n - (k - 1), 1)}k$$

or

$$C\left(3, 2\right) = \frac{C\left(3, 1\right) \cdot C(2, 1)}2$$

I was playing around with combinatorics, and realized that this holds true for all values that I put into it.

Comment: $C(n - (k - 1), 1) = n - k +1$, so this reduces to a well-known relation between binomial coefficients.

Comment: Just use the definition of $C(n.k)=(n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1))/k!$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a combinatorical explanation:

You can choose $k$ from $n$ items by

- choosing $k-1$ from $n$: $\color{blue}{\binom{n}{k-1}}$ and then
- choosing $1$ from the remaining $n-(k-1)$: $\color{blue}{\binom{n-(k-1)}{1}}$

But using this selection method the same selection can result in $\color{blue}{k}$ ways, since the $1$ you choose "last" can be one of the $k$. So,

$$\color{blue}{\binom{n}{k-1}\cdot\binom{n-(k-1)}{1}} = \color{blue}{k}\cdot \binom{n}{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

LHS is number of ways to choose $k$ objects from $n$ objects.

RHS is nothing but,
now from $n$ objects first choose $k-1$ objects and then from remaining $n-(k-1)$ objects choose $1$ obajects. But in this counting we are repeating same object for $k$ times so devide by $k$.

So LHS and RHS count same things. So are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Expanded with factorials,

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac1k\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}\frac{(n-k+1)!}{1!(n-k)!}.$$

The simplifications are obvious.

Answer (score -1):

LHS is the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from $n$ objects. 
RHS is nothing but, now from $n$ objects first choose $k - 1$ and then from remaining $n-(k-1)$ objects choose 1 obeject. 
but in this counting, we are repeating the same objects to objects K, so divided by Y
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZNI3.png)

$\frac { n ! } { k ! ( n - k ) ! } \simeq \frac { 1 } { k } \frac { n ! } { ( n - 1 ) ( n - k + 1 ) ! } \frac { ( n - k + 1 ) ! } { 1 ! ( n - k ) ! }$